# trRuntimeError : 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, classification

train_nn(resnet18_model, trainloader, testloader, loss_fn, optimizer, 20) -> loss_fn -> loss = loss_fn(ouputs, labels)
RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.